# Setting Brackets live preview content-types

Tags: adobe-brackets, contenttype

I am using Brackets live preview to handle some old website I have. It includes links that use shtml. Note I am not using SNI capabilities on these pages. However, it looks like the content-type sent by the server, is application/shtml, instead of text/html
This forces the file to be downloaded, instead of being displayed. Is there any way to change the content-type for this file? Is there any way to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution!
I go into 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\www\extensions\default\StaticServer\node\node_modules\connect\node_modules\send\node_modules\mime\types
I'm editing mime.types
Search for:
text/html                   html htm
And change it to 
text/html                   html htm shtml

Enjoy!

Comment: No idea how you found this but thank you!